# central email notification for airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, airflow, amazon-cloudwatch

We are using apache airflow in AWS environment for scheduling jobs. Airflow provides failure notification at task level. Howeve, I wanted to configure notification at airflow level. so even if dag does not have any notification configured, if any DAG failed some group will get notification.

I am thinking following for this.

1. Redirect the logs to s3
2. AWS lambda which listen to new log files
3. parse the logs file and if contains error send notfication

**the problem is.**
if is setup aws lambda on put, then as soon as file is created it will trigger the lambda and it might not have full log file.

The otherway I am thinking is to push logs to cloudwatch and have alerting from it.

Not sure how to achieve it. I am not getting information from AWS engineers either.

Comment: I'd say have airflow automatically export metrics (both platform-level, task-level as well as DAG-level) and then use `prometheus` / `grafana` for proper monitoring / alerting. Check [robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter](https://github.com/robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter)

Comment: thanks, I will look into this. However first i want to check if I can do with aws services.

Comment: airflow writes everything including states of it's `task`s & `dag`s in it's SQLAlchemy backend (meta-db). You can query it to retriever errors; but of course that poll-based approach would be very bad. Just thinking out loud here, but one could apply triggers on main tables like `dag_run`, `task_instance` for reactive notifications; or may even listen to `binlog`s generated by writes on this DB to perform stream-processing (maybe using just a lambda), and trigger notifications from there